# PL/SQL - Delete a character in a VARCHAR2

Tags: oracle, plsql, varchar2

(I'm sorry for my english...) I'd like to know if I can delete a character in a varchar2 :

```
FOR FF IN REQ LOOP
IF FF.COLUMN_NAME = ANCIEN THEN
  ORDRE_DYN := ORDRE_DYN || ANCIEN;
ELSE 
  ORDRE_DYN := ORDRE_DYN || FF.COLUMN_NAME;
END IF;

ORDRE_DYN := ORDRE_DYN || ' ' || FF.DATA_TYPE || '(' || FF.DATA_LENGTH;

IF FF.DATA_PRECISION IS NULL THEN
  ORDRE_DYN := ORDRE_DYN || ', ' || FF.DATA_PRECISION || '),';
END IF;
END LOOP;
```

At the last iteration, there is a comma that i want to delete, is it possible ? I know i can do a while loop but i still want to keep the for.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After your loop is done you can RTRIM the comma off:

```
END LOOP;

ORDRE_DYN := RTRIM(ORDRE_DYN, ',');
```

If a comma does not exist at the end of the string then no changes are made to the string.

[Oracle 11gR2 RTRIM documentation.](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions160.htm)